# Validate database schema programmatically in hibernate throws MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, database-schema

Trying to validate schema programmatically

```
@Autowired    
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
```

// code for getting hibernate configuration

```
private Configuration getHibernateConfiguration() {
        final PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo = localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getPersistenceUnitInfo();
        final Map<String, Object> jpaPropertyMap = localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap();
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl builder = new EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl(new PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor(persistenceUnitInfo), jpaPropertyMap) {
            @Override
            public Configuration buildHibernateConfiguration(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
                Configuration configuration = super.buildHibernateConfiguration(serviceRegistry);
                if (persistenceUnitInfo instanceof SmartPersistenceUnitInfo) {
                    for (String managedPackage : ((SmartPersistenceUnitInfo) persistenceUnitInfo).getManagedPackages()) {
                        configuration.addPackage(managedPackage);
                    }
                }
                return configuration;
            }
        };
        serviceRegistry = builder.buildServiceRegistry();


        return builder.buildHibernateConfiguration(serviceRegistry);
    }
```

This method tries to call the schemaValidator method from  Configuration class.

```
public void getSchemaValidationService(DataSource dataSource) {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        Dialect dialect = Dialect.getDialect(hibernateProperties);
        Configuration configuration = getHibernateConfiguration(dataSource);
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource().getConnection();
            DatabaseMetadata metadata = new DatabaseMetadata(connection, dialect, configuration);
            configuration.validateSchema(dialect, metadata);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    new SqlExceptionHelper().logAndClearWarnings( connection );
                    connection.setAutoCommit( false );
                    connection.close();
                    logger.error("Connection Closed : "+connection.isClosed() );
                    connection = null;
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.error("Datasource connection failed to close");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Using hibernate in multi-tenancy mode so trying to validate schema programmatically.

Schema validation works perfect, but after few minutes it tries to throw

MySQLNonTransientConnectionException in case if validation fails.

Any valuable suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue was dataSource was not closed when schema validation fails